# How to analyse data from the same group where some people have opted out and data is anonymous?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I have a peculiar situation, I am conducting research and had a group of students participate in it. I had them scored on (property) $X$ and say $n_1$ people participated.

After an intervention, I measured the same property $X$ but this time $n_2$ (where $n_2 < n_1$) people participated.

Now the catch is that the experiment is so designed that the forms are filled in anonymously and there is no way to compare the scores of the same individual.

So now I am left with the group mean and I want to run some tests on these.

I want to know -- which tests are most suitable for this kind of data?

Please explain the rationale as well or give hints /links so that I am convinced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have implicitly paired samples (before and after intervention) but because of anonymity, the pairing is lost.

As a result, if you want to test for a treatment effect, you're left with an independent samples two-sample test (you don't actually have complete independence because of the pairing effect, but it shouldn't matter in this case).

The most common procedures for that would be a two-sample $t$ test or a Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon test.

At the end you say "now I am left with the group mean" -- I hope you have more information than *just* the group mean, or there will be nothing you can feasibly do. If you have the original scores, you should be fine to do either procedure, or if you have the means, standard deviations and sample sizes you would be able to at least do the t-test.

Both tests make some assumptions, but the main difference in the assumptions (if you're testing means) is that the t-test makes the additional assumption of normality; if your two samples are not too strongly non-normal about their own group means, this won't really matter very much, but you would want to make some assessment of the suitability of that assumption. If you're specifically testing mean-shift alternatives, you should check that the shapes and spreads are similar even if you use Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney (it can be used without that assumption but the alternative doesn't have a location-shift interpretation any more).

Comment: Yes, I have the sample size ,standard deviation and means available pre and post intervention. But I am not sure whether the data that I have is normally distributed. Also the sample size is small i.e. less than 25.

Comment: Do you have the individual data or only those summary statistics?

Comment: Yes, I have individual data but anonymous data.

Comment: Then if you do a t-test, I'd suggest doing a Q-Q plot of the residuals (observations - group mean), and looking at the relative standard deviations, or perhaps some direct display of the raw data by group, like dotplots or stripcharts. In fact I'd do something like this no matter which procedure I considered. Is your alternative of interest specifically in a mean-shift or is some more general kind of difference of interest here?

Comment: Have you looked at any displays of your data?

Comment: Yes I had looked up the qqnorm plot in R and it doesn't shift too much from the normality i think. Thanks for the help . I will have to admit that I am new to statistics and sorry to say that I don't understand mean-shift as of yet. I will look up these terms and post my queries if any. Thanks again.

Comment: on 'mean shift'. Consider two different possibilities for treatment effect. (i) the treatment on average adds 3 to every 'pre' value.  (ii) the treatment on average doubles every 'pre' value. ... the first is a 'mean shift' (more generally a location-shift), while the second is a scale shift.

Comment: When you say you looked up the qqnorm plot in R - if you plotted only the raw data from both groups (i.e. without allowing for the potential difference in means) that plot could be misleading. If you looked at deviations from the group mean (or plotted them separately) that would be okay.